# Is it possible to get prediction accuracy after call model.predict_classes()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm new to python neural networks. I used ml.net in the past. There was easy to take accuracy of each predicted example f.e -> my model recognized bike on photo with acc = 60%.

Now I need to make similar thing in python. I'm using keras and tensorflow.

This is how I make my prediction:

```
predict = model.predict_classes(data)
```

It returns predicted class but how to get accuracy of this prediction?

Comment: Just one clarification, what you want is called confidence, not accuracy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the evaluate function in Keras:  https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate

Some additional specific metric functions:  https://keras.io/metrics/#usage-of-metrics

Also, there are some good examples to get you started in case you run into issues:  https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `model.predict(<np.array>)`

If your task is classification and you are doing multi-class classification, remember to use `softmax` at the end to get the correct probabilities.

Comment: [http://www.insightsbot.com/blog/G1Za1/keras-multi-class-classification-introduction] like here, you just need a dense layer with `activation="softmax"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for probability of each class if it's true so you can use: "predict_proba" for example if your feature victor is "data" in sklearn it would be:

```
 pro=model.predict_proba(data)
```

Which pro is an array contain probabilities of each class. In your case for example 60% bike, 30 % car and so on.